# Adding member function to a C++ class bound to Lua

Tags: c++, lua, lua-c++-connection

I have been working on how to bind C++ classes to Lua for use in a game engine, and I have run into an interesting problem. I have been following the tutorial on this website: http://tinyurl.com/d8wdmea. After the tutorial, I realized that the following code he suggested:

```
local badguy = Monster.create();
badguy.pounce = function(self, howhigh, bonus)
    self.jumpbonus = bonus or 2;
    self:jump(howhigh);
    self:rawr();
end
badguy:pounce(5, 1);
```

Would only add the pounce function to that specific instance of a Monster. So I changed the script that he suggested to the following:

```
function Monster:pounce(howhigh, bonus)
    print("in pounce function");
    print(bonus);
    self.jumpbonus = bonus or 2
    self:jump(howhigh);
    self:rawr();
end
local badguy = Monster.create();
badguy:pounce(5,1);
```

However, when I call the pounce function, the script breaks.  After further testing, the only way I was able to successfully call the pounce function was by calling the function as a static member of the Monster class (the code for the function stays the same):

```
Monster.pounce(badguy,5,1);
```

Syntactically, badguy:pounce(5,1) is correct, but isnt correctly calling the function. Am I just doing something wrong, or is this a limitation of the binding between lua and c++/how I am binding the two languages?

Comment: I see only Lua here, does this question really have anything to do with C++, or is this entirely a LUA question?

Comment: Does the "in pounce function" debug message print? Add some more debugging prints between each line of the code to find out exactly where it crashes and we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: Can you also add how the script breaks? What kind of error messages and traceback do you get? Does it go into the `pounce` function at all or do you get a `nil` value error etc.?

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, the Monster class is defined in C++, and was bound to Lua using static method wrappers to the member functions. One thought of mine was that it is because the pounce function isn't defined in C++, and I am creating it in Lua, that it isnt working as a static function.

Comment: @Deco Nope, the "in pounce function" does not print when being called like a member function. the script breaks right when I try to call the pounce function as a member function.

Comment: @VictorT. I actually have been having an issue with the syntax for the lua debug functions. It might be that I haven't spent enough time looking for what I needed to use, but any pointers in the right directions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand the question, and may have an idea of the solution.  The is technically no link between the lua Monster 'class' and the C++ Monster class.  When you call a lua 'member function' on a given lua object, it has no knowledge of the particular Monster object in C++.  If you want to call a non-static method of a C++ object you cannot use a lua C-function to do this.  You would need to have a user-data somewhere attached to your lua object that has a pointer to the C++ object (be very careful about object lifetimes - you must use full-userdata and override the __gc in lua with a C-function that destroys the C++ object).  In this case, you can declare a private static C++ method on the Monster class that expects this userdata, and then casts the pointer and calls the non-static member function for this particular C++ monster object, with the given arguments. (I hope I understand your question, and that my answer is written clearly enough.)

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
function Monster:pounce(howhigh, bonus)
```

this is a shortcut for

```
Monster.pounce = function(self, howhigh, bonus)
```

So obviously calling this by

```
Monster.pounce(badguy, 5, 1);
```

as you did makes sense.

But you want to do something different: From your C++ module you get a table named `Monster`. You don't want to manipulate this table itself, as it (only?) contains an entry named `create`, a `monster`'s constructor.

I must admit that I don't completely get the code you linked to, but assuming a monster's method are accessed by a metatable, you could insert the method `pounce` in that metatable.

Answer (score -3):

it is not possible to call your C-Object/Function directly with all of its parameters. You have to register a C-Function into your Lua-State. This function has to look this way:

```
static int myfunc (lua_State *L) {
  // your code
  return X;  /* X = number of results */
}
```

This function receives only the Lua-State as parameter. All the parameters of the Luafunction call laying on the lua stack. You have to pop then from the Stack and Call your C++ method with it.

The registration of a function is quiet simple and done with two lines of code:

```
lua_pushcfunction(l, myfunc);
lua_setglobal(l, "myfuncnameinlua");
```

You can find more information about that in [this chapter](http://www.lua.org/pil/26.html) of the Book "[programming in lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/index.html)"

The thing you want to do, implementing an Lua-Object is a bit more complicated, because you have to register a metatable to create a Lua Object but your Lua to C interface are still functions of the explained kind.

You can also lean to implement a Lua-Object in Roberto Ierusalimschy's book on [chapter 28](http://www.lua.org/pil/28.html)

I hope this will help you

Comment: RTFQ, before you tell them to RTFM, please.